# How to modify the YT video code to make it work for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript

I have this code from YT video, but it only works for one object. I want it to work with multiple objects taken by id name.

I tried to make this 'const fill' like it is made with 'const empty of empties' but it didn't work

```
<div class="empty">
    <div class="fill" draggable="true"> </div>
  </div>

  <div class="empty"> 
  </div>

  <div class="empty">
  </div>

<script>

const fill = document.querySelector('.fill');
const empties = document.querySelectorAll('.empty');

// Fill listeners
fill.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
fill.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);

// Loop through empty boxes and add listeners
for (const empty of empties) {
  empty.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  empty.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  empty.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  empty.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}

// Drag Functions

function dragStart(e) {
  this.className += ' hold';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');
  setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'invisible'), 0);
}

function dragEnd() {
  this.className = 'fill';
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.className += ' hovered';
}

function dragLeave() {
  this.className = 'empty';
}

function dragDrop() {
  this.className = 'empty';
  this.append(fill);
}

</script>
```

I want it to work for multiple objects that I can drag and drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were really close! I'm assuming you can only drag on element at a time, so you'll want to store the currently dragged element in some variable that is available to the functions. I added comments after each line I edited from your attempt.

```js
let dragging;  // A place to store the dragging element
const fills = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
const empties = document.querySelectorAll('.empty');

// Fill listeners
for (const fill of fills) {
fill.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
fill.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

// Loop through empty boxes and add listeners
for (const empty of empties) {
  empty.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  empty.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  empty.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  empty.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}

// Drag Functions
function dragStart(e) {
  dragging = this;
  this.className += ' hold';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');
  setTimeout(() => (this.className = 'invisible'), 0);
}

function dragEnd() {
  this.className = 'fill';
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.className += ' hovered';
}

function dragLeave() {
  this.className = 'empty';
}

function dragDrop() {
  this.className = 'empty';
  this.append(dragging);  // Use the element
  dragging = undefined;  // Reset the variable
}
```

```css
.empty {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 1em;
}

.fill {
  min-height: 1em;
}

#a.fill {
  background-color: red;
}

#b.fill {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="empty">
    <div class="fill" draggable="true" id='a'> </div>
</div>

<div class="empty"> 
    <div class="fill" draggable="true" id='b'> </div>
</div>

<div class="empty">
</div>
```